# Strange behaviour SOAP-HTTPS webservice on JBoss 7.4 HA cluster

Tags: java, soap, https, jboss, cxf

We have EAP 6.3 (AS 7.4-final) running in HA mode on two Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Microsoft Azure Cloud servers.The two nodes are load-balanced through Azure load-balanced set for HTTPS.

Calling the SOAP service through HTTP is no problem, But for HTTPS we get some strange results. Calling through HTTPS the first one or two times, after a JBoss (re)start, succeeds. After this next tries result in this exception:

```
13:07:43,555 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-57) Interceptor for {http://www.enexis.nl/SCiP/admin/2013/10/}ScipAdminService has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't parse stream.
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1445)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
        at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.0.CR1.jar:2.3.0.CR1]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:353) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.4.0.Beta4.jar:7.4.0.Beta4]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:551)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:600)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:625)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:331)
        at __redirected.__XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(__XMLInputFactory.java:142) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1443)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Strange I/O stream, returned 0 bytes on read
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.BaseReader.reportStrangeStream(BaseReader.java:216)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.loadMore(UTF8Reader.java:375)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:111)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.initialLoad(ReaderBootstrapper.java:250)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.bootstrapInput(ReaderBootstrapper.java:133)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:546)
        ... 37 more
```

We also tried with a stand-alone JBoss not running in HA mode, but got the same results ending in the exception above.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  We're seeing this exact same error, under the same scenario when SSL is enabled.

Comment: There must be a bug in JBoss, though we couldn't find it reported anywhere, so it might have been a transient issue.  The issue occurred for us when we upgraded from JBoss EAP 6.1.0.Alpha1 to JBoss EAP 6.3.0.Alpha1.  Upgrading further to JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA, and the issue went away.  Should've known not to use an alpha release (doh!)